# There was no electromagnetic field at the moment of the Big Bang. Did it appear later?

Tags: electromagnetism, quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, big-bang, grand-unification

After the big bang, the fundamental interactions were one, but over time they began to separate. This is evidenced by the Grand Unification model. Do I understand correctly that at the time of the big bang, for example, there was no electromagnetic field?

Comment: Grand Unification is speculative. There is no accepted GU model.

Comment: On the other hand, it’s a respectable “mainstream” topic. So I didn’t mean to suggest that you shouldn’t get an answer about how grand-unified models work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here is the current](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Astro/timlin.html) Big Bang timeline:

[image: bb]

It is expected that the present form of the theory fitting the existing data and observation is arrived after [symmetry breaking.](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Forces/unify.html). It is expected that all forces were unified at the beginning. If theory succeeds to unify quantized gravity with the other forces, one might talk of symmetry breaking for gravity.Also the Grand Unified theories are still under study.  The electroweak symmetry breaking is in better shape theoretically and it is within the Standard Model of particle physics.

You ask:

> at the time of the big bang, for example, there was no electromagnetic field?

What is the electromagnetic field, to search for it at the time of the Big Bang?

We have the classical electromagnetic field , a solution of Maxwell equations, but it does not belong to the quantized regime of an early universe model.

There is the quantum mechanical ensemble of photons that [reproduce the mathematics of the classical electromagnetic field,](https://motls.blogspot.com/2011/11/how-classical-fields-particles-emerge.html) and there are the charges of particles and their  magnetic moments. Those should exist after the inflationary epoch in the plot above,when the quark gluon plasma dominates the universe . It has no meaning to ask about charges and magnetic moments before the inflationary epoch, because the theories are under continuous evolution, and there are still unsolved theoretical problems, as is the observed baryon asymmetry in our universe.

So I would answer that there is no electromagnetic field at the beginning of the Big Bang.

Comment: And what does it mean in the beginning, all forces were unified in terms of quantum fields. That is, instead of many fields, there was one, which, as a result of symmetry breaking, "split" into several?

Comment: @АрманГаспарян  These fields would be many dimensiional, so as to finally split into quarks and electrons etc. The symmetry and group representations should be there  in the mathematics., but one would not be able to distinguish them experimentally.

Comment: That is, at high energies it is something unified and multidimensional, but when the energy falls, it breaks down into different interactions?

Comment: @АрманГаспарян  well , within the field theory, the gauge bosons separate due to the acquisition of mass  that is why the unified interaction (all gauge bosons are mass zero) becomes separate. But the group sructure should be there before symmetry breaking.

Comment: I'm wondering in what sense interactions are unified in the GUT. Is it one interaction, one force that split?

Comment: I mean, before the different forces separated, were there quarks, electrons, neutrinos, photons, gluons and so on?

Comment: @АрманГаспарян   As an example of group structure. look here  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eightfold_way_(physics)#/media/File:Baryon_decuplet.png  that is a group structure  : now there is a mass difference between the particles, but even if all the masses were the same , still the structure of quantum numbers would be there (charge and strangeness). These are composites, so these are  just an illustration of  what it means to have the same group structure. The SU(2) structure of the standard model with elementary particles should be there, before and after symmetry breaking.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that in the GUT era there were as many types of force carriers, that is, bosons, as after this era (although after that some bosons simply acquired mass)? That is, after breaking the symmetry and separating different forces, the number of particle types did not change?

Comment: @АрманГаспарян  In EW yes, at an elementary particle level everything was there except with zero mass, They are there but all the same. zero mass. The weak gauge bosons separated from the electromagnetic. When unified there were just four zero mass bosons. I do not know GUTs in any detail. the gluon has already mass zero. it is the  W and Z that come out of symmetry breaking with a mass. But symmetry breaking means that the number of elementary particles should not change.